# Volume on the container of docker-compose is empty or has weird content

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm having docker issue and I have no idea if this is an docker environment issue. It's a fresh install of Docker-tools 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302 on Windows 10 Home using VirtualBox.

With this simple local file hierarchy:

```
docker
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ index.html
|_ code
   |_ index.html
   |_ empty_folder1
   |_ test_folder
      |_ test_file.txt
      |_ empty_subfolder1
      |_ empty_subfolder2
```

And this simple compose file (no port opened, for simplicity):

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Then executing

```
$ docker exec -i docker_web_1 bash
$ ls /usr/share/nginx/html
```

It displays the following files according to the volume I set

- [no volumes] displays the usual files with the default nginx index.html
- ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html displays an empty folder
- ./:/usr/share/nginx/html displays a "code" folder, that is empty. This used to show files I had deleted before and were not on my local folder anymore like if there was some ghost cache somewhere, but after creating a new docker-machine, it is now only listing the empty "code" folder.

I tried building the container with a clean slate like this but it doesn't change anything:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q) --force
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker-compose rm --all && docker-compose pull && docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on??

Comment: An UP for you. I'm in same boat and cannot find nothing.. Is it possible we are the only two with same problem? :)

Comment: No idea haha! But I wrote to docker support and got no answer either, you should try also in case you are luckier

Comment: I think that we need use Dockerfile to overwrite base configuration: https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/ .. I will try

Comment: I just tried to use the -v params in command line. I tested nginx image. I can edit local file and get reflect live. My start command: `docker run --name test -v /home/sineverba/domapidocker/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -P -d nginx` You can see that Im mapping my html folder to base /usr/share/nginx.

Comment: So it's all working for you? I had to reformat my computer after getting a new HDD and switch to another project for a while, so my environment is now different and have no idea if I will get the same error, or if it will work. Will get back eventually to that project and see for sure however

Comment: For the moment I tested only a simple index.html. I did change, F5 and bam! changed. So I think it will work also for PHP, for example